# Building a string with For Next Loop value for a UserForm control name

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, userform

I'm trying to build the value

```
If UserForm1.p1OptionButton.Value = True
```

Where the 1 in p1OptionButton is the value of a For Next loop counter but I'm getting errors however I try and construct it. If I use

```
Dim iPart As Integer
For iPart = 1 to 6
If "UserForm1.p" & iPart & "OptionButton.Value" = True
.... blah blah blah rest of the code
Next iPart
```

I get this error:

> Runtime error 13 type mismatch.

If I leave the " out from around the other parts of the string it doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Say for example you have 6 `OptionButton`s and a `CommandButton` on your form then you can iterating the options per the code sample below. If you set a variable to be an `OptionButton` and then assign one of the forms `Controls` to that variable you can access its properties e.g. `Name` and `Value` etc very easily.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim opt As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 6
        Set opt = UserForm1.Controls("p" & i & "OptionButton")
        If opt.Value = True Then
            MsgBox opt.Name & ":" & opt.Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the correct approach and I've upvoted it accordingly, but it's worth noting that although the controls collection is 0-based you're actually selecting opt by its name, not its ordinal.  In your example, when i = 0 then  'UserForm1.Controls("p" & i + 1 & "OptionButton")' evaluates to 'UserForm1.Controls("p1OptionButton")' so you might as well make your life easier by using 'For i = 1 to 6' and 'UserForm1.Controls("p" & i & "OptionButton")'.

Comment: @Winterknell - yes of course, you are right. I will update the example.

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I have done any VBA so may be a bit rusty :)

The error you are getting is because you are comparing a String with a Boolean, hence the Type Mismatch

You could try using the following code to access a control dynamically:

```
Forms("UserForm1").Controls("p" & iPart & "OptionButton").Value = True
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're trying to compare a string to a boolean value, so it's not going to work in the way you want it to. If you want it to work better, you could do something similar to simply just going through each of the possible values (IE UserForm1.p1OptionButton.Value, UserForm1.p2OptionButton.Value, etc)